# Receive and process JSON POST in Java using Jackson

Tags: java, json, rest, jackson

I have application server, say App1 sending a REST POST in JSON to another server, say server1 at some path (server1/path). How can I read the fields from the JSON POST everytime something is posted and perform some action.

I am currently using Jackson API and this is what I have so far:

```
@POST
@Path("tcp")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response getInfo(InputStream stream) throws IOException {
    try {
        ObjectNode jsonTree = (ObjectNode) mapper().readTree(stream);
        JsonNode someField = jsonTree.get("fieldname");

        if (someField != null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid field in post request");

        // Do something with someField here everytime something is POSTed....
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
    }

    return Response.ok(root).build();
}
```

The `mapper()` is a method provided by this package `org.onosproject.rest` available at [here](https://github.com/opennetworkinglab/onos/blob/master/core/api/src/main/java/org/onosproject/rest/AbstractWebResource.java)

Comment: You forgot to tell us what is wrong with what you have so far.

Comment: I am getting this response: {
  "code": 500,
  "message": "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.BooleanNode cannot be cast to com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode"
}

Comment: and you forgot to tell us what mapper() is.  Or at least how it is imported.

Comment: and please put these clarifications in the post, because comments are transient.